# date: extra operand error on the wrong variable

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, amazon-s3

I'm working on a script to delete bucket objects from S3 based on the date they were created but more importantly the type of file they are. I keep getting the error:

```
 date: extra operand 'PREBACKups2/' 
 Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

Which is really interesting since I'm not entering anything close to that.
Here's what I'm entering on the CLI:

```
./s3DeleteByDate "sqlbackup.sql07.useast1/Backups2" "2m"
```

Here's the code base I'm working with:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: ./s3DeleteByDate "bucketname" "2m"

aws s3 ls s3://$1 | grep " DIR " -v | while read -r line;
 do
  createDate=`echo $line|awk {'print $1" "$2'}`
  createDate=`date -d -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "$createDate" +%s`
  olderThan=`date -d $2 +%s`
  if [[ $createDate -lt $olderThan ]]
   then
     fileName=`echo $line|awk {'print $4'}`
     if [[ $fileName == "" ]]
      then
        printf 'Deleting "%s"\n' $fileName
        aws s3 rm  "$fileName" --exclude "*" --include "*.tmp"
     fi
  fi
done;
```

Now I'm fairly certain it's actually looking at the data but somehow crashing before it executes.

Comment: What's the exact value of `$line` that gets echoed to `awk`? Your quoting isn't correct, so I think that's the problem. Try `createDate=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1" "$2}')`.

Comment: I did you fix and it didn't change a whole lot. Now what I did do was I entered: aws s3 ls s3://sqlbackup.sql01-perf.useast1/Backups2 and it just says: PRE Backups/ which is indeed the folder name that I'm accessing. I'm so dumb. It needs another / on the end to read everything.

Comment: It's impossible for me to say what the value of `createDate` will be without knowing what the value of `line` is, because without knowing that, I can't tell you want `awk` will produce.

Comment: Well, that output is clearly not a date, so why do you think it's a valid argument for the `date` command?

Comment: Well I added the "/" to the name I was calling in there and that fixed it. Now it's giving me the error date: extra operand '2017-03-23 15:48:02'

Comment: If you are using GNU `date`, it doesn't take a `-f` argument to specify the input format. It's treating the `-f` as the argument to `-d`, using `"%Y...%M"` as the output format, and wondering what the remaining two arguments are for. You just want `date -d "$createDate" +%s`.

Comment: Has anyone ever told you you're a miracle worker? Because you are haha. Thank you. The only error that's showing up now is date: extra operand '+%s'. Other than that the script appears to be working but it's definitely slower with this error.